# Cycles Render CPU Usage Low with Dual Xeon

Tags: performance

low CPU usage on Dual Xeon (128GB RAM) when rendering "blenderman" using command line and Cycles on Ubuntu and Win10. Using latest 2.8 build.

Single i7 3rd Gen gets upto 100% using GUI and CMD on Windows 10...

**GUI and CMD on i7 and Win 10 using "blender -b Blenderman.blend -f 2"**

[image: GUI and CMD on i7]

**CMD on Dual Xeon on Win10** **"blender -b Blenderman.blend -f 2"**

[image]

**CMD on Dual Xeon on Ubuntu..."blender -b Blenderman.blend -f 2"**

[image]
[image]

What gives?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if we could make a chart of how many of us would like to use a computer like that, it would be at 100% or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your threads exceed the tiles number (*cool!*).**

You can't render a tile with more then one hyper core thread. Change the tiles size

[image]

See this, I got 512x512 tile size with Full HD size rendering, there are 8 tiles been rendering, with 100% CPU in i7-4770k(4C8T).

[image]

But with 1024x1024 tiles, there are only 4 tiles to render. So 4 Thread are used with 70% CPU load(Hpyer thread)

[image]

Comment: Perfect that works a treat. thanks for the info. It was certainly a nice problem to have to solve :)